# +load method not getting invoked in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am aware that +(void)load method gets called in ios even before the main function.
In my case it is only getting invoked with UIView and not with UITextView.

- Are there any files that need to import ?
- Does load method work only for certain set of class.
  Please provide necessary input regarding conditions required in order to invoke +(void)load method in ios.

Getting invoked here :

```
@implementation UIView (SomeMethodSwizzling)
+(void)load{



}
@end
```

Not Getting inovked here .

```
@implementation UITextView (SomeMethodSwizzling)
+(void)load{

}
@end
```

Comment: Be careful overriding methods in a category. That is undefined behavior in Objective-C.

Comment: Not for `+load`. That's the one magical case where it is actually defined.

Comment: @RobNapier Interesting tidbit. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this downvoted, when this is valid question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual reason is that you're not actually linking the file. Most common cause is that you don't directly use anything declared in it (you sometimes need to pass `-objc` to the linker to fix that). Another cause is you just forgot to add the file to the target (I see that happen a lot).